# Add Date & Time and Convert to UTC

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two dates. Date1 and Date2

Date1 contains "10/12/2010 12:00:00AM". Date2 contains "10/10/2010 03:00:00PM"

I want to extract only the date from Date1 and extract only the time from Date2 and join them.

Example "10/12/2010 03:00:00PM".

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
DateTime date3 = date1.Date + date2.TimeOfDay;
```

Where does UTC come into it?

Answer (score 2):

[`DateTime.Date`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.date.aspx) will get you the date part and [`DateTime.TimeOfDay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx) will get you the time part, so:

```
DateTime date3 = date1.Date + date2.TimeOfDay;
```

should do what you want.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to convert to UTC, you probably want to do so with both dates, for cases where the timezone difference crosses into another date. Maybe you don't for reasons that aren't clear, in which case remove the relevant conversion from below:

```
date1.ToUniversalTime().Date + date2.ToUniversalTime().TimeOfDay
```

This also assumes the dates are both known to be in local time. You may wish to add a check of the `Kind` property:

```
(date1.Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc ? date1 : date1.ToUniversalTime()).Date + (date2.Kind == DateTimeKind.Utc ? date2 : date2.ToUniversalTime()).TimeOfDay
```